# How to create a bag of words using Weka?

Tags: nlp, weka

I have a corpus of documents and I want to represent each document as a vector. Basically, the vector would have 1 for words that are present inside a document and for other words (which are present in other documents in the corpus and not in this particular document) it would have a 0. How do I create this vector for all the documents in Weka?

Is there a quick way to do this using Weka? I also want Weka to remove stopwords and so some pre-processing if possible before it creates this vector.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter.

It has options for binary occurrence and stopping, amongst many others, such as stemming, truncating the word list, discarding infrequent terms, case folding.